# I've gained the privilege to vote up on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

I've just visited Stack Overflow and I got this message:

[image]

is it correct?

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: you should freehand-circle your rep to state your point...

Comment: @Tobias do you like the color's nuance that "perfectly" mixes with the orange bar creating an incredible palette :-/?

Comment: @systempuntoout: yeah, it's perfect. did you click the notification away or is it still there btw?

Comment: Wait till you get unicorn tagging, it's awesome!

Comment: I never received such a notification.

Comment: I don't think I have either

Comment: @Tobias clicked and gone forever

Comment: The punctuation of that sentence is terrible =o Missing a semi colon and a period.

Comment: but to be fair, you have gained the priv to vote up, we are not lying :) ... I don't know if to status-by-design this or status-wont-fix or what with this question? ... it is fixed for you after all :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bit glitchy, I seemed to have missed marking those notifications as "sent" when I deployed the system, there are 30 more users with 5k rep on SO that will be affected.

But let me take a step back and explain how the new system works:

We have these privilege things on each site:

[image: privs on SO]

For each privilege we have the rep required and 2 flags that dictate who gets notified. **Veteran users** are users that have an associated account on another SO site, non-vets do not.

*As you can see, veterans get significantly less notifications than non-vets (by-design)*

We have another table that tracks *which user* was notified of *which privilege*.

When the system was deployed, I ran a script that "pretended" that all users with more rep than 10 got all the historic notifications. I seemed to have missed the vote-up priv there that caused this issue.

Whenever, a user's reputation changes we check to see if they were notified for all the privileges they have, if any are missing – we insert notifications.

We **never**, notify a user twice of the same privilege.

Comment: Making any user with more than one account a 'vet' seems rather silly to me.

Comment: Aww!! I can't edit it; it's just a picture!

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking this is a one-time non-issue due to the rollout. I had a similar experience on Programmers SE. All existing users were probably awarded all statuses they'd achieved at once, because they weren't notified before, because there was no notifier yet.

To strictly answer your question, yes, it is correct. You *can* vote up, after all. Just think of it as the system being really slow to let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Meh. Just *one* privilege?

[image]

Comment: @Reg that's not a circle!

Comment: I can't draw circles freehand any more accurately than that...

Comment: @system, it is, it just fell over.

Comment: @Reg oh, actually it's easy. You just need three tools: a drinking glass, a pair of scissors, soldering iron. 1. Turn a glass of water upside down 2. Move your mouse around it for the first half 3. Cut the mouse cable 4. Resolder the cable on the other side of the glass 5. Complete the circle [Tips: with a wireless mouse you just need a water glass].

Comment: @system: a drinking glass I have. As a Russian, I am obliged to always carry one with me. However, as a Russian, I am also obliged to use it for purposes entirely different from the profane ones you outlined above. Also, what is this "water" thing people won't stop telling me about?

Comment: @Reg, yeah, yesterday when I was passing the Red Square I was stopped by a KGB officer.  He searched me, and, having found no drinking glass, punished me by confining me into the basement of Lubyanka until today. :-(  And, by the way, "water" is that creepy thing that runs through our toliets.  I still wonder, why people put it into their glasses...

Comment: @Pavel: OMG you are posting from the KGB, err, FSB headquarters? Pics or it didn't happen! (BTW, [what do you mean by "Red" Square?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/))

Comment: @system: your algorithm only works for round mice!  I have no wireless mouse so I wasted all of my mice trying!!!

Comment: @mario nooooooo, I missed that caveat in the instruction steps; I am really sorry for that!