# Wrong congrats message on 500 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, notification-bar

A little bit strange, on SO I climbed over 500 rep (a second time, first time was ~2 weeks ago, but it went back under 500 after SO outage that forgot an accepted answer), and I get the message

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege to vote up

There must be something wrong...

Comment: got the same message today.. so i guess it has nothing to do with 500 rep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've gained the privilege to vote up on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a self correcting bug, sorry about the unwanted notification.

see: [I've gained the privilege to vote up on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow/68264#68264)