# No privilege notification after reaching 1K

Tags: support, status-bydesign, privileges

Is this by design?

Comment: Maybe wait for a few hours first? There could be delays.

Comment: @KennyTM: Maybe. But having the privilege and being notified of it several hours later seems kind of odd :)

Comment: No, not really odd.  You don't get notified of new messages right away either, unless they're still waiting when you come back to the site a few hours later.  Maybe it is a bug, but I expect it's by design.

Comment: Better late than premature notification spilling a load of what you can access/do if the rep is reversed/recalced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [I've gained the privilege to vote up on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow/68264#68264)

In particular, as a veteran user you get significantly less notifications. The next notification you should expect is at 1500 when you are able to edit tag wikis.

Comment: Why do I get less notifications? I recently gained the privilege "vote down" and "less ads" and didn't get a notification. I really love the popup telling me that I gained a certain privilege...