# 1k established user privilege notification no longer shown in new profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, notifications, privileges

I'm used to seeing privilege milestones shown as a pop-over notification covering the privilege section the first time I visit the (new) profile page after earning them. For example, I join a new site and immediately dismiss the CW edit notification.

But just now, I hit 1k here on Meta and checked my profile fifteen or twenty minutes later and saw no such milestone notification, just a green (un)progress bar coolly saying "well, you have 1k, that's great, just 1k to go before you hit a milestone". That's kind of disappointing on general principles and, in this particular case, especially unhelpful, since some of the details of usercards are sufficiently finicky that almost any user might conceivably wish to easily refer back to the docs when setting up their brand-new user card on a new site.

This is not a dupe of [No privilege notification after reaching 1K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68662/no-privilege-notification-after-reaching-1k), despite the similar names, as that was asking for a topbar notification. (I wouldn't mind that either, but it's not as big a deal.)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I observed this earlier on another site, probably ELL, but it was hard to verify at the time.