# "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – vote up"

Tags: support, status-bydesign, notifications, up-votes, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I've gained the privilege to vote up on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow)

[image: Congrats, you've gained the privilege - vote up]

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67754/ive-gained-the-privilege-to-vote-up-on-stack-overflow), but not only it's worded differently, I also don't have 5k reputation as the questioner (not even one tenth of 5k), so I don't know if it's a bug or it's some sort of ironic way of telling me to vote up once in a while.

The latter sounds possible because I'm not that active (yearling with just 500 rep!), but I do vote up more than I vote down.

[image]

Bug? Only happening to me?

Comment: while you might not have the same amount of rep, the question and it's answer are still completely applicable. This question is duplicate.

Comment: By the way the notification is still there and I don't know how to remove it :P

Comment: Awesome, the close button appeared after a while. Phew, quite freaky.

Comment: I also see this today, 7 December 2010. I have 419 reputation.

Comment: @pauloya Weird, I think this is a bug but mods can't care less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When's the last time you were on the site; was it more than a couple weeks ago when privilege wikis launched? If so, it sounds like the same bug you linked to; the ability to vote up is at 15 rep, and waffles said a bunch of people that already had that privilege (which would include you) were alerted when they shouldn't have been, so if this is your first time to the site since then the alert would've sat in your message queue until now

Comment: I've visited the site before yesterday without recieving the notification, but I can't be sure, maybe I wasn't logged in. anyway I thought "there are 30 more users with 5k rep on SO that will be affected." meant I wouldn't for not having 5k.