# Why don't we receive notifications for obtaining the "approve tag wiki edits" privilege?

Tags: support, privileges, achievements-dialog

Yesterday evening I obtained the [Approve tag wiki edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege on English Language & Usage, yet I didn't see a notification in my achievements inbox:

[image]

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? I know that veteran users aren't notified of most low-level privileges (under 2k on graduated sites), but I think I've received notifications for all higher level privileges. There's a eight-year old table [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68264/295232), but the reputation levels have been adjusted and this particular privilege didn't even exist back then. I'd appreciate an update of that table; maybe it's even possible to integrate it into the one in [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/295232).

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't remember getting a "Congrats! You gained new privilege" notification for.... years. You got any at all? EDIT: checked with sock, saw lots of notifications. So my best guess is that they unticked the "Notify Veterans" checkbox for "Approve Tag Wiki Edits" privilege when adding it. :)

Comment: Yeah, most vividly for 2k, 3k and 10k. It's been a while since I've reached 5k on a site, though. FWIW, I'm fine with this privilege deemed to be not important enough (that's why I'm not tagging it as a [bug]); I'd just like to have an update on the notification settings table.